# Writing multiple UIWebViews as UIImages to PDF file

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview, uiimage

I'm using chart-creation library TWRCharts, which is a subclass of UIWebView, to draw multiple charts to a PDF file, and I'm having trouble adding more than one to my PDF file.

I use the following code to call my chart-creation methods:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self createTapImageFromChart];
    [self createCogImageFromChart];
}
```

And these are the methods being called (partial):

```
- (void)createTapImageFromChart {

    // Chart View
    _chartViewTap = [[TWRChartView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 400, 300)];
    _chartViewTap.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    // Hide the chartview until needed
    _chartViewTap.hidden = YES;

    // Add the chart view to the controller's view
    [self.view addSubview:_chartViewTap];
}

- (void)createCogImageFromChart {

    // Chart View
    _chartViewCog = [[TWRChartView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 400, 300)];
    _chartViewCog.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    // Hide the chartview until needed
    _chartViewCog.hidden = YES;

    // Add the chart view to the controller's view
    [self.view addSubview:_chartViewCog];
```

}

Then the code I use to capture the charts and draw them to the PDF file is:

```
//////////// Capture Tap Chart ///////////////

_chartViewTap.hidden = NO;
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(_chartViewTap.bounds.size);
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
UIGraphicsPushContext(context);
[_chartViewTap.layer renderInContext:context];
UIGraphicsPopContext();
self.chartImageTap = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
_chartViewTap.hidden = YES;

///////////// End Capture Tap Chart //////////

UIImage *anImage = self.chartImageTap;
CGRect tapHeader = [self addText:@"Finger Tap Test"
                            withFrame:CGRectMake(kPadding, blueLineRect.origin.y + blueLineRect.size.height + kPadding, _pageSize.width - kPadding*2, 4) fontSize:18.0f];
CGRect imageRect = [self addImage:anImage
                          atPoint:CGPointMake(/*(_pageSize.width/2)-(anImage.size.width/2)*/ kPadding, tapHeader.origin.y + tapHeader.size.height + kPadding)];

//////////// Capture Cog Chart ///////////////

_chartViewCog.hidden = NO;
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(_chartViewCog.bounds.size);
CGContextRef contextCog = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
UIGraphicsPushContext(contextCog);
[_chartViewCog.layer renderInContext:contextCog];
UIGraphicsPopContext();
self.chartImageCog = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
_chartViewCog.hidden = YES;

///////////// End Capture Cog Chart //////////

UIImage *anImageCog = self.chartImageCog;
CGRect cogHeader = [self addText:@"Cognitive Test"
                       withFrame:CGRectMake(420, blueLineRect.origin.y + blueLineRect.size.height + kPadding, _pageSize.width - kPadding*2, 4) fontSize:18.0f];
CGRect imageRectCog = [self addImage:anImageCog
                          atPoint:CGPointMake(420, blueLineRect.origin.y + blueLineRect.size.height + kPadding)];
```

When I run this and save the PDF, I get this:

[image]

But when I comment out [self createTapImageFromChart]; and the "Capture Tap Chart" section, I get this in the PDF:

[image]

I need both charts to appear side-by-side at the same time. I plan to add two more charts below, also side-by-side. Could some please offer advice/code for how to fix this?  I believe that the problem is in my context. I am just not sure how to make it so that the second chart is not omitted when the first chart is printed.

Comment: Can you clarify what "fix this" means in this context? Are you concerned about the vertical positioning of the red line? The overlap of the cognitive chart with its label? The missing cognitive test in the first image?

Comment: I'm sorry for not being clear. I would like both charts to appear at the same time. Imagine the first image, but with the chart in the second image also on the PDF. I will end up adding two more charts beneath those as well. I think that it has something to do with my image context but not sure.

Comment: Where does the method `-addImage:atPoint:` come from? Is that one of your own, or is it in a PDF or chart-handling library?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding modifying the position of charts views added as sub-views. Ex.

```
_chartViewTap = [[TWRChartView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 400, 300)];
_chartViewCog = [[TWRChartView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(410, 0, 400, 300)];
```